# NVL() degrades the performance

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

> Delivery tables is having 1731791+ rows.
>   homedl column having 0,1,NULL values.

I want to fetch the records whenever homedl column is not equal to 1.

Which query will give best performance here

```
select homedl 
  from delivery 
 where item_id='1343275' 
   AND NVL(homedl,0) <> 1 
   and item_type=0;
```

OR

```
select homedl 
  from delivery 
 where item_id='1343275' 
   AND (homedl<>1 or homedl is null)  
   and item_type=0;
```

Comment: Just check the execution plan, maybe ?

Comment: Have you tried running both and looking at the performance and explain plans? If you have an index on item_id then it should be irrelevent.

Comment: Are the query plans different?  I would expect the two queries to produce identical plans and, thus, to perform identically.  If there is an index on `homedl`, either using a function or looking for `NULL` values will likely prevent the index from being used.  If you are stating that you are getting poor performance, I would suspect that adding the `NVL` prevents an index from being used which can be remedied by creating a function-based index.

Comment: here item_id is indexed column?

Comment: Is ITEM_ID a primary or unique key?

Comment: I'd favour a function-based index in general, but here the not-equals predicate usually makes the optimiser reluctant to use an index of any sort. Whether it should depends on the fequency of rows meeting the condition, and if the condition eliminates vey few rows then an index is not going to be helpful.

Comment: You might consider using Coalesce() in future instead of Nvl() -- ANSI syntax, more flexible in terms of the number of possible arguments, and short-circuit evaluation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first , lets look at the data , how many delivery records have the homedl=1 or homedl=0 or homedl is null :

```
select homedl , count(*)
  from delivery 
group by homedl
```

if the count of nulls and ZEROs is significantly smaller than the count of ONEs then you should create a function based index that will be used for this query :

```
create index user2582602_idx on delivery (NVL(homedl,0));
```

and then select like this :

```
select homedl 
  from delivery 
 where item_id='1343275' 
   AND NVL(homedl,0) = 0 
   and item_type=0;
```

Comment: Thanks. above logic is in live now... I am not seeing any major time difference after adding this conditions..

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question depends on many factors, e.g. RDBMS vendor, what type of index, if any, is present on `homedl` column. I presume that `item_id` and `item_type` are already indexed appropriately.

You could better use the following query:

select homedl from delivery where item_id='1343275' AND `coalesce(homedl, 2)<>1` and item_type=0;

If `item_id` is primary key, then query execution time wouldn't matter for different queries you mentioned, because `explain [sql query]` will show you that the key used is `PRIMARY`.

Comment: It depends on RDBMS vendor as well, because bitwise index implementation might vary across different vendors or worse may not be available at all.